# onSaveInstanceState not getting variable after onCreate

Tags: java, android, variables

Hi can someone explain me please what I am doing wrong because I cannot get a variable from savedInstanceState, int "score" every time I change my screen orientation it resets the variable.

```
int score;
EditText et;
String etString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score");
        et.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("etText"));
        Log.d("TEST2", "score " + score);
    } else {
        score = 0;
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);

    etString = et.getText().toString();
    outState.putString("etText", etString);
    outState.putInt("score", score);
    Log.d("TEST", "score " + score);
}

public void performAction(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button:
        score += 1;
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Score: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

}
```

Please help if you know the solution.

Comment: score = 0; after changing my screen orientation; even tho I incremented it and it's higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using a method that is from Lollipop, change to the version that is available since Android 1.0

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

see the different method signature?

Comment: change it to:     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle outState) {
        super.onCreate(outState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if (outState != null) {
            score = outState.getInt("score");
            et.setText(outState.getString("etText"));
            Log.d("TEST2", "score " + score);
        } else {
            score = 0;
        }

    } still nothing

Comment: @John did you see the change that Budius told you to make? Judging by your comment here, you've changed the wrong method. Read the answer again and change the right code, then let us know.

Comment: @John read it again. You should change the `onSavedInstanceState` method.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I was a bit distracted and didn't noticed that.

Comment: By the way is there a way to use method from Lollipop and still save variables ?

Comment: there's a matching `onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` in Lollipop. But I've never tested.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [`onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState) instead of getting value in `onCreate`. The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem. It's true it only get's called with there's something to restore, but the same value is also passed to onCreate and there's nothing wrong with the code `if(savedInstanceState!=null)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OrientationChangeActivity extends Activity {

private EditText edtUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);



    if (savedInstanceState != null /*&& savedInstanceState.getString("edt") != null*/) {
        edtUser.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("edt"));
        Log.e("Demo","==================================="+savedInstanceState.getString("edt"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("edt", edtUser.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}